# Query Active Directory via SQL Server Linked Server on Trusted Domain Returns Error

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, openquery

I think a similar question posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920175/sql-linked-server-query-for-ad-returns-msg-7321), but I am not sure if it is indeed the same solution for me.

I have a SQL Server 2000 instance on the local domain, I can query it without error. But I need to query another active directory on a trusted domain, when doing so I get the error:

> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Could not fetch a row from OLE DB provider 'ADsDSOObject'.
>   OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'ADsDSOObject' IRowset::GetNextRows returned 0x8007202b].

In the linked server properties:

```
local_domain\user
Impersonate is checked
Be Made Using the Security Context
Remote login:user@trusted_domain.com
Password Supplied
```

Again, querying the local domain works, but changing the query to trusted domain returns an error.  Both the local and trusted accounts have rights to active directory. I am not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Thanks!

Comment: Question may be better suited on DBA site as involves problems with linked servers not code.

Comment: Error `0x8007202b` resolves to `ERROR_DS_REFERRAL`.  The LDAP server is referring you to another server.  It could be something as simple as the SQL server can't find a DC in the other domain in DNS, or it might be that the ADSI provider explicitly won't refer to other servers.